# CAAnimation with an transform rotation over an point

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation

I'm trying to animate the rotation of a layer of a view over an arbitrary point. The start position of the animation will be a `90º` rotation from the end and final position. This view occupies all the screen except the status bar.

I'm trying to use the following code (with a translation, followed by a rotation and an anti translation) but, however starting and ending in it, the animation isn't centered on the point, but wobbles around it.

```
CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation   animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
animation.duration = 1;
animation.additive = YES;
animation.removedOnCompletion = YES;
animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved;

//The point that should be used as the center of rotation
CGPoint cursorCenter=self.angleCenter;
//The center of the view
CGPoint linesCenter=lines.center;

//The transformation: translate->rotate->anti-translate
CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DIdentity;
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, cursorCenter.x-linesCenter.x, cursorCenter.y-linesCenter.y, 0.0);
transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(-90), 0.0, 0.0, -1.0);
transform = CATransform3DTranslate(transform, linesCenter.x-cursorCenter.x, linesCenter.y-cursorCenter.y, 0.0);

animation.fromValue =[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:transform];
animation.toValue =[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DIdentity];    

[lines.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"90rotation"];
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I wrote a [blog post called "translate rotate translate?"](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/) a while back that talks about just this kind of animation. That may be worth reading.

Comment: I'd already read it. The problem it's that I'm using auto layout. The solution on the stack overflow  link talks about a layer transform, but I'm already using that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to make translations to rotate over a aspecific point. Just change the **`anchorPoint`** of the layer **to adjust center of the rotation**.

> The origin of the transform is the value of the center property, or
>   the layer’s anchorPoint property if it was changed.

About anchor point and how to specify it:

> You specify the value for this property using the unit coordinate
>   space. The default value of this property is (0.5, 0.5), which
>   represents the **center** of the layer’s bounds rectangle. All geometric
>   manipulations to the view occur about the specified point. For
>   example, applying a rotation transform to a layer with the default
>   anchor point causes the layer to rotate around its center. **Changing
>   the anchor point to a different location would cause the layer to
>   rotate around that new point.**

[image]

Based on [CALayer Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint) and [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CoreAnimationBasics/CoreAnimationBasics.html)